# What are the Hebrew titles for synagogue functionaries in various communities?

Tags: synagogue, hebrew, words

In every Ashkenazic synagogue I've seen, the fellow calling up people to the *Bima* is called a "gabbai."  (Which was originally a Hebrew word for "collector", as in Tzedaka collector; I can see how the phrase transitioned.)

What about the synagogue president?  I think I've heard "nasi beit hakneset", though in a German-influenced synagogue they had a Mi Shebeirach for the president, referring to him as "parnes" [rhymes with "bar-mace"]-- which can mean "leader" or "economic provider."

I've heard of one Sephardic community (I don't know of which origins) where what we call the Gabbai was called the Parnes, but then saw an Iranian-American synagogue where he was called Gabbai.  Can anyone clarify this for me, or add to this?

Comment: Historically, like that of the Gabai,  I believe the "Chazan" had a more significant roll in the shul than being a cantor.

The Meturgeman used to interpret the Torah into Aramaic during its reading.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard *shamash*, who does light menial labor about the synagogue; *shlep shamash*, an informal/jocular term for the person who volunteers to carry *chumashim* back to the shelf after *k'rias hatora* and *sidurim* after prayers; *gabay*, not only the person who calls people to the Torah but also any similar functionary, such as one who appoints *baale t'fila* and one who records promises of future donations; *n'si bes hak'neses*, *nasi*, and *rosh hakahal*, all president; *rav*, rabbi; and *gabay rishon*, who calls people to the Torah, to distinguish him from *gabay sheni* and *gabay sh'lishi*, who may have other jobs, but also fill in for the *gabay rishon*, in that order, in his absence, to call people to the Torah. These were all in various *Ashk'nazi* synagogues.